# Join 2 sets based on default order

Tags: postgresql

How do I join 2 sets of records solely based on the default order?

So if I have a table x(col(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) and another table z(col(a,b,c,d,e,f,g))

it will return

```
c1 c2
-- --    
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
7   g
```

Actually, I wanted to join a pair of one dimensional arrays from parameters and treat them like columns from a table.

Sample code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Test"(timestamp without time zone[],
                                  timestamp without time zone[])
  RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
curr refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN curr FOR 
        SELECT DISTINCT "Start" AS x, "End" AS y, COUNT("A"."id") 
        FROM UNNEST($1) "Start" 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT "End", ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ("End")) rn
                FROM UNNEST($2) "End" ORDER BY ("End") 
        ) "End" ON ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ("Start")) = "End".rn 
        LEFT JOIN "A" ON ("A"."date" BETWEEN x AND y) 
        GROUP BY 1,2 
        ORDER BY "Start";
    return curr;
END

$BODY$
```

Comment: It'd be good to be more specific about what you mean by "default order" here. Do you want pair-wise groupings of the output of these data sets when sorted by their values, like `select col from x order by col`? Or do you want the *physical* order, the order you get from `select * from x` without any `order by`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, to answer the *real* question that was revealed in comments, which appears to be something like:

> Given two arrays 'a' and 'b', how do I pair up their elements so I can get the element pairs as column aliases in a query?

There are a couple of ways to tackle this:

- If and only if the arrays are of equal length, use multiple `unnest` functions in the `SELECT` clause (a deprecated approach that should only be used for backward compatibility);
- Use `generate_subscripts` to loop over the arrays;
- Use `generate_series` over subqueries against `array_lower` and `array_upper` to emulate `generate_subscripts` if you need to support versions too old to have `generate_subscripts`;
- Relying on the order that `unnest` returns tuples in and hoping - like in my other answer and as shown below. It'll work, but it's not guaranteed to work in future versions.
- Use [the `WITH ORDINALITY` functionality added in PostgreSQL 9.4](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/action/patch_view?id=1074) (see also [its first posting](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20130123062943.GB26369@fetter.org)) to get a row number for `unnest` when 9.4 comes out.
- Use multiple-array `UNNEST`, which is SQL-standard but [which PostgreSQL doesn't support yet](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/EFFDE903-E7DF-4E03-B7B9-99AC9D391D8B@emc.com).

So, say we have function `arraypair` with array parameters `a` and `b`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION arraypair (a integer[], b text[]) 
RETURNS TABLE (col_a integer, col_b text) AS $$
  -- blah code here blah
$$ LANGUAGE whatever IMMUTABLE;
```

and it's invoked as:

```
SELECT * FROM arraypair( ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], ARRAY['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'] );
```

possible function definitions would be:

### SRF-in-`SELECT` (deprecated)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION arraypair (a integer[], b text[])
RETURNS TABLE (col_a integer, col_b text) AS $$
    SELECT unnest(a), unnest(b);
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Will produce bizarre and unexpected results if the arrays aren't equal in length; see the documentation on set returning functions and their non-standard use in the `SELECT` list to learn why, and what exactly happens.

### `generate_subscripts`

This is likely the safest option:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION arraypair (a integer[], b text[])
RETURNS TABLE (col_a integer, col_b text) AS $$
    SELECT
       a[i], b[i]
    FROM generate_subscripts(CASE WHEN array_length(a,1) >= array_length(b,1) THEN a::text[] ELSE b::text[] END, 1) i;
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

If the arrays are of unequal length, as written it'll return null elements for the shorter, so it works like a full outer join. Reverse the sense of the case to get an inner-join like effect. The function assumes the arrays are one-dimensional and that they start at index 1. If an entire array argument is NULL then the function returns NULL.

A more generalized version would be written in PL/PgSQL and would check `array_ndims(a) = 1`, check `array_lower(a, 1) = 1`, test for null arrays, etc. I'll leave that to you.

### Hoping for pair-wise returns:

This isn't guaranteed to work, but does with PostgreSQL's current query executor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION arraypair (a integer[], b text[])
RETURNS TABLE (col_a integer, col_b text) AS $$
 WITH
    rn_c1(rn, col) AS (
      SELECT row_number() OVER (), c1.col
      FROM unnest(a) c1(col) 
    ),
    rn_c2(rn, col) AS (
      SELECT row_number() OVER (), c2.col
      FROM unnest(b) c2(col)
    )
    SELECT
      rn_c1.col AS c1, 
      rn_c2.col AS c2
    FROM rn_c1 
    INNER JOIN rn_c2 ON (rn_c1.rn = rn_c2.rn);
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

I would consider using `generate_subscripts` much safer.

### Multi-argument `unnest`:

This *should* work, but doesn't because PostgreSQL's `unnest` doesn't accept multiple input arrays (yet):

```
SELECT * FROM unnest(a,b);
```

Comment: Thanks, you've been very helpful. I wonder why are you committed to your answers. Do you get something from those stackoverflow points? Or you just feel like helping people?

Comment: @William A good question. A significant part of it is that *I* learn a lot through the process; it's how I became properly familiar with CTEs (`WITH` queries), window functions, and more. I work professionally with Pg, and Stack Overflow has been a useful learning tool, though I think I'm starting to reach the limits of that. It's also interesting and diverting. There are times when I get a bit sick of half-assed low-effort questions, but I tend to just ignore them for a while. I used to write a lot on the PostgreSQL mailing list; this is just an alternative really.

Comment: @CraigRinger Nice work! Have you considered putting your generate_subscript "array_pair" function on the pg wiki  https://wiki.postgresql.org?

Comment: @bma I probably should.

Answer (score 1):

```
select x.c1, z.c2
from
    x
    inner join
    (
        select
            c2,
            row_number() over(order by c2) rn
        from z
        order by c2
    ) z on x.c1 = z.rn
order by x.c1
```

If `x.c1` is not `1,2,3...` you can do the same that was done with `z`

---

The middle `order by` is not necessary as pointed by Erwin. I tested it like this:

```
create table t (i integer);
insert into t
select ceil(random() * 100000)
from generate_series(1, 100000);

select
    i,
    row_number() over(order by i) rn
from t
;
```

And `i` comes out ordered. Before this simple test which I never executed I though it would be possible that the rows would be numbered in any order.

Comment: can I use it without the order by?

Comment: @William The outer one is certainly not necessary. The inner one I guess is necessary, not sure.

Comment: Without an explicit ORDER BY there is no guarantee of the order of returned results.

Comment: @William: There are *three* instances of `ORDER BY`. The "outer" one is only needed to get the combined rows sorted. The "middle" one serves no purpose here. The "inner" `ORDER BY` in the window for `row_number()` is essential.

Comment: @Erwin Yes I forgot the one in the window. I was not sure the "middle" one was not necessary but now it is tested in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

By "default order" it sounds like you probably mean the order in which the rows are returned by `select * from tablename` without an `ORDER BY`.

If so, this ordering is *undefined*. The database can return rows in any order that it feels like. You'll find that if you `UPDATE` a row, it probably moves to a different position in the table.

If you're stuck in a situation where you assumed tables had an order and they don't, you can as a recovery option add a row number based on the on-disk ordering of the tuples within the table:

```
select row_number() OVER (), *
from the_table
order by ctid
```

If the output looks right, I recommend that you `CREATE TABLE` a new table with an extra field, then do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to insert the data ordered by `ctid`, then `ALTER TABLE ... RENAME` the tables and finally fix any foreign key references so they point to the new table.

`ctid` can be changed by autovacuum, `UPDATE`, `CLUSTER`, etc, so it is *not* something you should ever be using in applications. I'm using it here only because it sounds like you don't have any real ordering or identifier key.

If you need to pair up rows based on their on-disk ordering (an unreliable and unsafe thing to do as noted above), you could [per this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/52fbc/4) try:

```
WITH
rn_c1(rn, col) AS (
  SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ctid), c1.col
  FROM c1 
),
rn_c2(rn, col) AS (
  SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ctid), c2.col
  FROM c2
)
SELECT
  rn_c1.col AS c1, 
  rn_c2.col AS c2
FROM rn_c1 
INNER JOIN rn_c2 ON (rn_c1.rn = rn_c2.rn);
```

but *never* rely on this in a production app. If you're really stuck you can use this with `CREATE TABLE AS` to construct a new table that you can start with when you're working on recovering data from a DB that lacks a required key, but that's about it.

The same approach given above might work with an empty window clause `()` instead of `(ORDER BY ctid)` when using sets that lack a ctid, like interim results from functions. It's even less safe then though, and should be a matter of last resort only.

(See also this newer related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17762282/398670)

Comment: Craig thanks for the answer, this is actually related to that unnest answer of yours. Basically I want to join 2 arrays (from parameters) that are unnested and use them like they're both columns that can be referenced. The problem is I want to join them both so they're in the same row with the same order.

Comment: @William Well, why didn't you say so? (Writing new answer; this one remains valid for the question you *seemed* to be asking).

Comment: Sorry, wanted to make it as simple as possible. I've updated the question.

Comment: @William Understandable, but in this case oversimplified to the point where it wasn't clear what was desired. It's always worth explaining a little about the background and the *why* for your *how*, or backlinking to a prior question. Anyway, new answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

I had what I think is an interesting variant: I needed to insert in two tables, where the sequence is on the first table's id, the first table also gets literals, but the second table needs to get the results of a sequence. My insert looks like this (Postgres):

```sql
WITH q1 AS (SELECT col0 FROM ...),
     q2 AS (SELECT row_number() OVER () AS ord, q1.* FROM q1),
     i1 AS (INSERT INTO table1 (col1) SELECT 'literal' CROSS JOIN q2 RETURNING id),
     i2 AS (SELECT row_number() OVER () AS ord, i1.* FROM i1)
     INSERT INTO table2 (id, col2) SELECT (id, col0) FROM q2 JOIN i2 USING (ord);
```