# How keep data don't sort?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Table A:

```
Col1 Col2
12    a
12    c
12    b
```

If i code : `Select * from A;`
Result is:

```
Col1 Col2
12    a
12    b
12    d
```

I want get data is:

```
Col1 Col2
12    a
12    c
12    b
```

How get data don't sort?

[image]

Comment: The rows returned from a select without an `order by` are not sorted. Any order you see is pure coincidence. The order you see can and will change depending on other queries in the system and updates to the table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Post your comment as an answer. I for one would vote for it

Comment: How Index of row insert?

Comment: Is there an auto_increment column or a timestamp column in your table?

Answer (score 3):

The crucial thing to understand is that SQL tables *do not have an ordering*. The order of rows you see when you `SELECT` without an `ORDER BY` only stays the same because it's quicker for the database to get them in that order than some other order. PostgreSQL will only return rows in this order when you do a sequential scan on the table; if it can use an index for the query then you will generally get the rows in some other order.

You might find [this answer I wrote earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17645032/398670) informative.

In PostgreSQL, `UPDATE`s to rows can move them to a different location within the table, changing the order they're returned in.  So can the background autovacuum process and various other operations like `VACUUM` and `CLUSTER`.

So you must *never* rely on the "default" ordering for anything. If you want to give rows some kind of order, they *must* have a key on which you can sort them.

If you have created a table without a key and now realise it should have one, you might be able to recover from the situation by using the `ctid` system column. Do **not** rely on this for production use, it's a system-internal column that's visible to users only for emergency recovery and diagnostics purposes. First, see if the physical on-disk ordering is actually the order you want:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER () AS mytable_id, *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ctid;
```

If it is, you can add a new key column that's pre-set to an auto-incremented key applied in the on-disk row order. There are two ways to do this. The safest is:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE mytable IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;
ALTER TABLE mytable RENAME TO mytable_old;

CREATE TABLE mytable (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, LIKE mytable_old INCLUDING ALL);

INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT row_number() OVER () AS id, *
FROM mytable_old
ORDER BY ctid;

SELECT setval('mytable_id_seq', (SELECT max(id)+1 FROM mytable));

COMMIT;
```

then once you're sure you're happy with the results, `DROP TABLE mytable_old;`. See this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2cb99/2

A quick and easy but less safe way is to just create the column and rely on PostgreSQL re-writing the table from beginning to end:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN mytable_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

There is *absolutely no guarantee* that PostgreSQL will assign the IDs in order, though in practice it will do so. See [this SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/80533/2).

Be aware that when you use a `SEQUENCE` (which is what a `SERIAL` column creates) there are a few behaviours you might not expect. When you're inserting multiple rows at once, the rows might not necessarily get assigned IDs in the exact order you expect them to, and they might "appear" (become visible) in a different order to the order they were assigned IDs and inserted in. Also, if transactions roll back, the generated ID is thrown away forever, so you get gaps in the numbering. This is very good if you want your database to be fast, but it's not ideal if you want gap-less numbering. If that's what you need, search for "postgresql gapless sequence".

Answer (score 2):

To add to the very comprehensive answer given by Craig Ringer, you may want to consider re-framing the problem: *why* do you want the rows to show in that particular order? Clearly, that order has some particular meaning, and "they happened to be inserted in that order" is letting the technicalities of the database lead the application, rather than the other way around.

It might be, for instance, that these rows represent some kind of event, and you want to retrieve them in the order that the events occurred. In this case, the appropriate ordering column would be a timestamp; like an auto-increment sequence, you can give it a default value of when the row was inserted (but can over-ride that by inserting into the column explicitly, or updating values later, if necessary):

```
ALTER TABLE some_table ADD COLUMN event_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT ( NOW() );
```

Alternatively, perhaps it is actually based on the display label which will be shown on the UI, in which case you just need to `ORDER BY` that display label, having ensured the database is using the right `collation`.

Finally, maybe it is an entirely arbitrary display order, which can be tweaked to bring common or important items to the top of a menu. In that case, the display order is itself a property of the items being modelled, so should have its own column in the table. Since `order` is a SQL keyword, I often call such columns `order_hint`, so that I can say `ORDER BY order_hint` without worrying about specially quoting the column name.

Comment: Well said and well explained.

Answer (score 1):

a_horse_with_no_name gives the correct answer in the comment.  This is to address how to add the auto-increment column.

When you create the table, use something like:

```
create table A (
    Aid int not null auto_increment primary key,
    col1 int,
    col2 varchar(255)
)
```

When you insert into it, explicitly list columns:

```
insert into A(col1, col2)
    select 12, 'A';
```

Now you have the data in the format you want, with the column `Aid` providing "insert order".  You can then do:

```
select col1, col2
from A
order by id;
```

This returns the data in "insert order".  Note that because of updates and deletes, the data may actually be arranged on the pages differently from the input order.  The `order by`, though, explicitly re-sorts the data.

Being able to see the insert order is one of the reasons why I always use auto-incremented primary keys in all my tables.

Comment: But my table has not id ,it only has index

Comment: Actually, `ORDER BY id` isn't necessarily the insert order in more complex environments like those that're generating and caching blocks of IDs, those using distributed sequences in logical replication, etc. Even in a simple setup the insert order isn't necessarily the same as the commit order, so a row might be inserted but not yet visible when a "later" row is already inserted and visible. For that reason I think it's unwise to use generated IDs for ordering.

Comment: @CraigRinger Indeed, there is some argument for never using auto-increment columns, relying instead on a GUID or similar, so that there is no temptation to read meaning into what should be an arbitrary ID. See my answer below suggesting that the question should be re-framed.

Comment: @IMsOp I sometimes think PostgreSQL should default to passing generated sequence values through [a non-repeating pseudo-randomization function like a Feistel network](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt) (in C, not PL/PgSQL, of course). It'll never happen because that'd slow things down, but it's be nice just to break people's expectations of sequences being ordered.