# Adding the results of two select queries into one table row with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, concatenation

I am attempting to return the result of two distinct select statements into one row in PostgreSQL. For example, I have two queries each that return the same number of rows:

Select tableid1, tableid2, tableid3 from table1

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| tableid1 | tableid2 | tableid3 |
+----------+----------+----------+
|        1 |        2 |        3 |
|        4 |        5 |        6 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Select table2id1, table2id2, table2id3, table2id4 from table2

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| table2id1 | table2id2 | table2id3 | table2id4 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         7 |         8 |         9 |        15 |
|        10 |        11 |        12 |        19 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Now i want to concatenate these tables keeping the same number of rows. I do not want to join on any values. The desired result would look like the following:

```
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| tableid1 | tableid2 | tableid3 | table2id1 | table2id2 | table2id3 | table2id4 |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|        1 |        2 |        3 |         7 |         8 |         9 |        15 |
|        4 |        5 |        6 |        10 |        11 |        12 |        19 |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

What can I do to the two above queries (select * from table1) and (select * from table2) to return the desired result above.

Thanks!

Comment: do you need rows ordered by some column? I mean do you mind having `tableid1` = 4 in the first row of result and `tableid1` = 1 in the second?

Comment: Yes, I am feeding the result back into java and I need to refer to the columns in a set order. I'm actually doing something like (select tableid1, tableid2, tableid3 from table1) and (select table2id1, table2id2, table2id3, and table2id4 from table2) so if they could stay in the same order as that, that would be great

Comment: @user2255175 There *is* no ordering in those `SELECT`s. The database server can return them in any order it wants. You need an `ORDER BY` clause. It's only coming back in some particular order by luck at the moment.

Comment: ... and really, no matter what you do, you *are* doing a join. You're effectively asking "How do I do a join without doing a join".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have what you want, as you wrote the question. Your two `SELECT`s don't have any `ORDER BY` clause, so the database can return the rows in whatever order it feels like. If it currently matches up, it does so only by accident, and will stop matching up as soon as you `UPDATE` a row.

You need a key column. Then you need to join on the key column. Anything else is attempting to invent unreliable and unsafe joins without actually using a join.

Frankly, this seems like a pretty dodgy schema. Lots of numbered integer columns like this, and the desire to concatenate them, may be a sign you should be looking at using integer arrays, or using a side-table with a foreign key relationship, instead.

Sample data in case anyone else wants to play:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(tableid1 integer, tableid2 integer, tableid3 integer);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6);

CREATE TABLE table2(table2id1 integer, table2id2 integer, table2id3 integer, table2id4 integer);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (7,8,9,15), (10,11,12,19);
```

Depending on what you're actually doing you might really have wanted arrays.

I think you might need to read these two posts:

- [Join 2 sets based on default order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642600/join-2-sets-based-on-default-order/17645032#17645032)
- [How keep data don't sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761368/how-keep-data-dont-sort/17762282#17762282)

which explain that SQL tables just don't have an order. So you cannot fetch them in a particular order.

**DO NOT USE THE FOLLOWING CODE, IT IS DANGEROUS AND ONLY INCLUDED AS A PROOF OF CONCEPT**:

As it happens you *can* use a set-returning function hack to very inefficiently do what you want. It's incredibly ugly and *completely unsafe without an `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT`s, but I'll include it for completeness. I guess.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t1() RETURNS SETOF table1 AS $$ SELECT * FROM table1 $$ LANGUAGE sql;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t2() RETURNS SETOF table2 AS $$ SELECT * FROM table2 $$ LANGUAGE sql;
SELECT (t1()).*, (t2()).*;
```

If you use this in any real code then kittens will cry. It'll produce insane and bizarre results if the number of rows in the tables differ and it'll produce the rows in orderings that might seem right at first, but will randomly start coming out wrong later on.

**THE SANE WAY** is to add a primary key properly, then do a join.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` for join, but I'm not sure that you have guaranties that order of the rows will stay the same as in the tables. So it's better to add some order into `over()` clause.

```
with cte1 as (
   select
       tableid1, tableid2, tableid3, row_number() over() as rn
   from table1
), cte2 as (
   select
       table2id1, table2id2, table2id3, table2id4, row_number() over() as rn
   from table2
)
select *
from cte1 as c1
    inner join cte2 as c2 on c2.rn = c1.rn
```

Comment: The result of this are extremely unreliable without an `ORDER BY` clause in the `SELECT`s or the `row_number()` window clause.

Comment: @user2255175 Worked like a charm *for now*. This will break, and break horribly, later on. It's basically just generating a primary key on the fly for each table, *picking a key for each row essentially at random*, then joining the rows. Why not just *have a proper primary key on the tables in the first place*?